# How to return value from knouckout js Ajax call

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I have a `knouckout js` to return data to html template. But I can't able to return values from ajax call done function.

My knouckout js like below,

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'mage/url',
        'mage/storage'
    ],
    function ($, urlBuilder, storage) {
        'use strict';
        var url = null;
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Vendor_Module/test'
            },
            getUrl: function () {
                var serviceUrl = urlBuilder.build('module/index/index');
                var res = storage.post(
                    serviceUrl,
                    ''
                ).done(
                    function (response) {
                        /* here get results bot logs prinited in console */
                        console.log(response);
                        console.log(response.url);
                        url = response.url;
                    }
                ).fail(
                    function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                );
                /* But here url is null */
                console.log(url);
                return url;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

And my template is,

```
<a tittle="test" class="test-click" data-bind="attr: {'href': getUrl()}">Click</a>
```

From ajax call response I get the result, but that value not binds to my html template. Please help me someone to done this.

Comment: Controller returns an json array. In my console log it displays the array, So the problem is not in controller side

Comment: You need to return url in `done()` and `fail()` becuase when you call `getUrl()` function it will call ajax and run next statement which is `return url` and this url variable contains initialization value instead of ajax response value.

Comment: @PrincePatel yes exactly, how can I solve this

Comment: @VigneshBala you can use KO Observable Variable

Answer (score 1):

Try to init the variable **url** in a knockout observer as below, then on the response of ajax request, set the url back.

```
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'mage/url',
    'mage/storage'
],
function ($, ko, urlBuilder, storage) {
    'use strict';

    var url = ko.observable(null),
        getUrl = ko.observable(url() != null);

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/test'
        },

        url: url,

        getUrl: function () {
            var self = this,
                serviceUrl = urlBuilder.build('module/index/index'),
                returnUrl = '';
            var res = storage.post(
                serviceUrl,
                ''
            ).done(
                function (response) {
                    /* here get results bot logs prinited in console */
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(response.url);
                    returnUrl = response.url;
                    url(returnUrl); // Could try self.url(returnUrl);
                }
            ).fail(
                function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            );
            /* But here url is null */
            console.log(returnUrl);
            return returnUrl;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I will check this @Tuyen Nguyen

Comment: @VigneshBala Updated the answer

Comment: still the url not passed to template file, I guess this is async request issue